Higcharts annotations for various chart types
I'd like to know if annotations are supported for the following chart types:

Dependency wheel
Wordcloud
Pie/Donut
Treemap

I was able to get annotations work with "simple" charts that have X and Y axes, but I'm having trouble with those above. I would like to use mock points instead of point ID.
I tried specifying mock points just like I did for XY-axis charts, but I just could not get it to work.

In Highcharts, annotations are primarily designed for charts with x and y axes. The chart types you mentioned lack them so it's quite challenging to implement annotations there. Still it's possible (we only need to refer to the pixel coordinates rather than the point values).
Pie chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7j063hmg/
Treemap chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6us7eLbj/
It should work the same for the dependency wheel and wordcloud charts.
  annotations: [{
    labels: [{
      point: {
        x: 450,
        y: 129.2
      },
      text: 'x: {x}<br/>y: {y}'
    }]
  }]


That looks useful; do you know how Highcharts "decides" whether the values specified in the point property are data or screen coordinates? Does it go like if the chart is not an XY axis-like chart, then it's screen cordinates?
EDIT: I think I realized it might be the missing xAxis and yAxis props, right?

That's absolutely right. A demo with xAxis and yAxis props: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lb8tyks9/, and a demo without those props: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgs137hq/
